# Convert string in a existing dictionary to list

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dictionary below. I want to convert the string to list in Body section ("Body":"{"abc": "test"}"). My requirement is that I will post the whole dictionary and it will convert that into valid json object.

```
details = {
 "bb":[
  {
     "bb_name":[
        "baca"
     ]
  }
],
 "spd":[
  {
     "id_":1,
     "schema":{
        "method":"GET",
        "url":"http://api.myapi.com/12232",
        "Headers":[
           
        ],
        "Parameters":[
           
        ],
        "Body":"{\"abc\": \"test\"}"
     }
  }
]
}
```

Comment: `details["spd"][0]["schema"]["Body"] = eval(details["spd"][0]["schema"]["Body"])`?

Comment: The body key is dynamic. It may be another name or may be there have another key which has the same type of value. So in that case the above code will not worked.

Comment: And what have you tried, and what did not work?

Comment: I tried json.loads() but it didn't work.